# Python: How to convert .7z to .rar or .zip?

Tags: python, zip, 7zip, rar

How can I convert a .7z file to a .rar or a .zip file using Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two steps. First, uncompress the .7z file and then compress the content to zip file.

**Uncompress .7z file**

```
from lib7zip import Archive, formats

with Archive('filename.7z') as archive:
    # extract all items to the directory
    # directory will be created if it doesn't exist
    archive.extract('directory')
```

Reference: https://github.com/harvimt/pylib7zip

**Compress to zip file**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import zipfile

def zipdir(path, ziph):
    # ziph is zipfile handle
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            ziph.write(os.path.join(root, file))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('file.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    zipdir('tmp/', zipf)
    zipf.close()
```